# How can I implement custom user manager in django?

Tags: django, django-users

I create custom `User` model inheriting from `AbstractUser` in `Django`:

```py
class ChachaUser(AbstractUser):
    birth = models.DateField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
```

and my `CustomUserCreationForm` :

```py
GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('M', '남'),
    ('F', '여'),
)


class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    birth = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(
            years=range(1970, 2015)
        ),
        required=True,
    )
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, initial='M')

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = ChachaUser
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('birth', 'gender')
```

But I want to create a superuser using `python manage.py createsuperuser`, I have to implement `CustomUserManager`, too.

Any idea or example, please?

Comment: First instead to import `ChachaUser` use `get_user_model()` everywhere. If you need to add fields `gender, birth` to `createsuperuser` command use
`REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'birth', 'gender']`

Comment: @AnnaVracheva : It works well! thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

You're interested in [`UserManager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager) ([code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py)).

Example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager

class CustomUserManager(UserManager):
    # your methods

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # fields

    objects = CustomUserManager()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should implement a class that inherits from `BaseUserManager`. You must implement methods `.create_user` and `.create_superuser`. I strongly suggest you to put this class in a file `managers.py` in the same app as your custom `ChachaUser`  model.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email for user must be set.')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

For a complete guidance on creating a custom user model using either `AbstractUser` or `AbstractBaseUser` see [this tutorial](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-custom-user-model/).

Answer (score 0):

Or this way:

```py
class CustomUser(User):
    objects = MyManager()
    class Meta(object):
        proxy=True
```